# Advanced printf functionality in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, printf

Is there a way to get this functionality in PHP?
I want to be able to choose the array and the position it should read out. This is just example code.

```
<?php
$array[] = "Tim";
$array[] = "Harry";
$arrayb[] = "as";
$arrayb[] = "bla";
$arrayb[] = "zta";

echo printf("Hello %0[0]$s! I want %1[0]$s ti be %0[1]$s and %1[1]$s, %1[2]$s", $array, $arrayb);
#OUTPUT: Hello Tim! I want as to be Harry and bla, zta
```

Comment: Everything is possible, especially if not in such a preverted form. Why not to tell **a real case** instead of abstract senseless sketch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php#87031 - different syntax but same goal.

Answer (score 3):

```
vprintf("Hello %1$s! I want %3$s t0 be %2$s and %4$s, %5$s", array_merge($array,$arrayb));
```